# Метеринские и дочерние формы в Deplhi 2010

Tags: delphi

Есть одна материнская форма (`fsMDIForm`) и две дочерних (`fsMDIChild`). Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы при старте программы дочерние формы не загружались (были скрыты)?

Answer (score 2):

В настроечках проекта пункт меню **Project -> Options** на закладке **Forms** из списка **Auto-create forms** переместить в правый список дочернюю MDI форму с помощью стрелки вправо. А в процессе работы программы придётся создавать форму вручную - программно, например, при нажатии на кнопку (имена компонентов могут отличаться):

```
procedure TMainForm.ButtonCreateClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ChildForm:=TChildForm.Create(Owner);
end;
```